# Laravel Eloquent "With" and sub "With" relationship query -> pass Column Value as Where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery, relationship

I have 3 Models "Category" (tableName = 'categories'), "Brand" ('brands'), "Item" ('items')

Can I pass parent column value (e.g. categories) to use it in the Where clause?
Simple example:

```
Category::with(['brands' => function ($q) {
            $q->with(['items' => function ($query) use ($localWhereHas) {
                $query->whereColumn('category_id', 'categories.id');
            }]);
        }]);
```

**Relations are:**

Category Model:

```
public function brands(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class, 'category_brands')->withPivot('is_visible', 'addon_price');
    }
```

Brand Model:

```
public function items(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'brand_id');
    }
```

Item Model:

```
public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, "category_id");
    }
```

The main idea is that I need the structure to be nested like this Category->Brands->Items

The backup plan is to fetch All needed Categories and Foreach them to get as many as categories I have all Brands->Items, using categoryId ($category->category_id) .... but I don't like it

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't pass it directly because it is not the same context.

If you want to have  a display like this :

Category
-brand
-item

Then you should maybe just group your items by brand :

```
$categories = Category::with('items.brand')->get();
```

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->name}}
    @foreach($category->items->groupBy('brand_id') as $brand_id => $items)
        {{ $items->first()->brand->name }}
             @foreach($items as $item)
                  {{ $item->name }}
             @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```